# Convert a Notebook directly to a package with boiler plate

Tags: front-end, notebooks, packages, conversion

I want to be able to turn a bunch of notebooks I have into packages so I can more easily share them with others, without having to go through the boiler-plate of choosing which cells to export / doing a `"Save As..."`, re-indenting all of my input cells, writing usage messages, etc. All my code is in `"Input"` and `"Code"` cells.

How could I do this?

Answer (score 6):

Before we get into the weeds, here's an example of doing exactly this, just to see how it works:

```
$testNB =
  URLDownload[
   "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/b3m2a1/mathematica-tools/master/\
NotebookToPackage.nb",
   FileNameJoin@{
     $TemporaryDirectory,
     "NotebookToPackage.nb"
     }
   ];
Import["https://raw.githubusercontent.com/b3m2a1/mathematica-tools/\
master/NotebookToPackage.m"
  ];
NotebookToPackage[NotebookOpen[$testNB]] // CreateDocument;
```

---

So happily we can fill in most of the package boiler plate with just the code in the notebook, under a few assumptions:

1. All code in the `"Input"` and `"Code"` cells should be exported to the package
2. Every symbol defined in the `"Input"` and `"Code"` cells that starts with a capital letter should be exported to the package at top-level
3. The `Context` for the new package should be based on the file-name of the notebook

Of course, we could always add `Options` and customizations to get around any of these restrictions, but maybe that's for another day.

The hardest part here will actually be to pull the usage statements. In our code we may have things like:

```
`Pkg`mFunc[Verbatim[HoldPattern][f_], a_+b_]:=
  Module[{blahblah},
   ...
   ]
```

And how do we make a good usage message out of that?

I'd argue we'd want something like

```
`Pkg`mFunc::usage="mFunc[f] ..."`
```

So how do we get there. First off, we'll need a way to extract definitions from an expression. Since we don't want to capture things like:

```
Module[{tempFunc},
 tempFunc[]:=...
 ]
```

We'll need to make sure to do it only at the first level. But first we'll need to remove any first-level `CompoundExpression` calls, as they'd prevent us from accessing the definitions. A second issue is that you can define things like

```
HoldPattern[f[x_]]:=x
```

So we have to strip things like `HoldPattern` too

Altogether we get a function, `exprFindDefinitions`, which looks something like this:

```
definitionSanitize[expr_] :=
  HoldComplete[expr] //. {
     Verbatim[Verbatim][e_] :> e,
     Verbatim[HoldPattern][e_] :> e
     } // Apply[HoldPattern];
definitionSanitize~SetAttributes~HoldAllComplete

exprFindDefinitions[expr_] :=
  With[{eheld =
     Replace[HoldComplete[expr],
      HoldComplete[CompoundExpression[e___]] :>
       HoldComplete[e]
      ]},
   Flatten@{
     Cases[eheld,
      (SetDelayed | Set)[lhs_, rhs_] :>
       (definitionSanitize[lhs] :> rhs)
      ],
     Cases[eheld,
      (TagSetDelayed | TagSet)[tag_, lhs_, rhs_] :>
       ({definitionSanitize[tag], definitionSanitize[lhs]} :> rhs)
      ],
     Cases[eheld,
      (UpSetDelayed | UpSet)[lhs : _[e__], rhs_] :>
       Replace[
        {(subPatternPullHead /@ HoldComplete[e] // ReleaseHold)},
        HoldComplete[s_Symbol] :>
         ({definitionSanitize[s], definitionSanitize[lhs]} :> rhs),
        1
        ]
      ]
     }
   ];
exprFindDefinitions~SetAttributes~HoldAllComplete
```

This will pull out definitions from an *expression* and return them in a held format.

We'll then want a function that will figure out what the symbol in the definition is, depending on whether it was defined in an `OwnValues`, `DownValues`, `SubValues`, or `UpValues` like pattern:

```
Clear[ownPatternToUsage, downPatternToUsage, subPatternToUsage, 
  upPatternToUsage];
ownPatternToUsage[sym_Symbol :> u_] :=
  makeUsageRule[sym, sym];
ownPatternToUsage~SetAttributes~HoldAllComplete;
downPatternToUsage[(sym_Symbol)[args___] :> u_] :=

  makeUsageRule[sym, sym[args]];
downPatternToUsage~SetAttributes~HoldAllComplete;
subPatternPullHead[pat_] :=
  NestWhile[
   Extract[#, {1, 0}, HoldComplete] &,
   HoldComplete[pat],
   ! MatchQ[#, HoldComplete[_Symbol]] &
   ];
subPatternPullHead~SetAttributes~HoldAllComplete;
subPatternToUsage[subPat_ :> u_] :=

  With[{sym = Extract[subPatternPullHead[subPat], 1, Unevaluated]},
   makeUsageRule[sym, subPat]
   ];
subPatternToUsage~SetAttributes~HoldAllComplete;
upPatternToUsage[{sym_, p_} :> u_] :=
  makeUsageRule[sym, p];
upPatternToUsage~SetAttributes~HoldAllComplete;

Clear[exprDefinitionToUsage];
exprDefinitionToUsage[
   ({Verbatim[HoldPattern][sym_], Verbatim[HoldPattern][p_]} :> v_)
   ] :=
  upPatternToUsage[{sym, p} :> v];
exprDefinitionToUsage[
   (Verbatim[HoldPattern][own_Symbol] :> v_)
   ] :=
  ownPatternToUsage[own :> v];
exprDefinitionToUsage[
   (Verbatim[HoldPattern][down : (_Symbol)[___]] :> v_)
   ] :=
  downPatternToUsage[down :> v];
exprDefinitionToUsage[
   (Verbatim[HoldPattern][sub_] :> v_)
   ] :=
  subPatternToUsage[sub :> v];
```

This is then calling a function `makeUsageRule` which formats a `symbol` and `usage` pair into a `Rule` that will be interpreted as a usage message later. The function itself looks like this:

```
Clear[makeUsageRule, patternSanitize];
makeUsageRule[sym_Symbol, usage_] :=
  StringReplace[
    ToString[Unevaluated[sym], InputForm],
    $hiddenPackageExportContext -> ""
    ] ->
   Replace[patternSanitize[usage],
    HoldComplete[s_] :>
     StringReplace[
      ToString[Unevaluated[s], InputForm],
      $hiddenPackageExportContext -> ""
      ]
    ];
makeUsageRule~SetAttributes~HoldAllComplete;
patternSanitize[usage_] :=
  ReplaceAll[
   ReplaceRepeated[
    HoldComplete[usage], {
     (Verbatim[Pattern] |
         Verbatim[Optional] |
         Verbatim[PatternTest] |
         Verbatim[Condition]
        )[p_, _] :> p
     }],
   (s_Symbol?(Function[Null, Quiet[Context[#]] =!= "System`", 
        HoldAllComplete]) :> RuleCondition[
      ToExpression[$hiddenPackageExportContext <> 
        SymbolName[Unevaluated@s]],
      True
      ])
   ];
patternSanitize~SetAttributes~HoldAllComplete
```

Here's an example of what it's doing:

```
makeUsageRule[asd,
 asd[b_, {c_, g : _ : 1}, d_] /; $true
 ]

"asd" -> "asd[b, {c, g}, d]"
```

The right-hand side of that is a good start for a usage message.

So now that we can turn the notebook expressions into usages, we'll want to turn the notebook cells into usages, collect these, and format a new package notebook. We'll start with the cell conversion:

```
cellsBuildPackageCore[c : {___Cell}] :=
  (
   Begin[$hiddenPackageExportContext];
   (End[]; #) &@Replace[c,
     {
      cell : Cell[BoxData[b_], $codeExportStyles, ___] :>
       (
        Sow@
         ToExpression[b, StandardForm, exprFindDefinitions];
        Cell[
         BoxData@
          FrontEndExecute@FrontEnd`ReparseBoxStructurePacket[
            First@FrontEndExecute@
              FrontEnd`ExportPacket[cell, "InputText"]
            ],
         "Code"
         ]
        ),
      Cell[CellGroupData[cells_, state1___], state2___] :>
       Cell[CellGroupData[cellsBuildPackageCore[cells], state1], 
        state2]
      },
     1
     ]
   );
```

This goes through a list of `Cell` expressions and if they match our expectation for the form of a code cell (`$codeExportStyles` is and alias for `"Input"|"Code"`) we convert them into an expression, pull the definitions from that (in held form, of course), and sow these. Then we reformat the boxes in the cell so they'll appear with the appropriate indentation in the package.

Then we write our core function, `NotebookToPackage` to pull this all together (note that we have a function `defsUsagesCell` to format our usages into their cell and a function `notebookExtractPackageName` that pulls the appropriate package name from a `NotebookObject`):

```
Clear[makeUsageBoxes];
makeUsageBoxes[name_, strings : {__}] :=
  RowBox[{
    RowBox[{
      RowBox[{name, "::", "usage"}],
      "=",
      "\"" <> StringRiffle[strings, "\n"] <> "\""
      }],
    ";"
    }];
defsUsagesCell[defList_] :=
 With[{chunks =
    GroupBy[
     exprDefinitionToUsage /@ defList,
     First -> Last
     ]
   },
  If[Length[#] > 0,
     Cell[
      BoxData@
       RowBox@
        Riffle[
         Prepend[
           RowBox@{"(*", RowBox@{"Package", " ", "Declarations"}, 
             "*)"}]@
          KeyValueMap[makeUsageBoxes, #],
         "\n"
         ],
      "Code"
      ],
     {}
     ] & /@ {
    KeySelect[chunks, 
     And @@ Through[{Not@*LowerCaseQ, LetterQ}@StringTake[#, 1]] &],
    KeySelect[chunks, 
     Or @@ Through[{LowerCaseQ, Not@*LetterQ}@StringTake[#, 1]] &]
    }
  ]

notebookExtractPackageName[nb_NotebookObject] :=
  StringReplace[
   Replace[
    Quiet[NotebookFileName[nb]],
    {
     s_String :>
      FileBaseName[s],
     $Failed :>
      AbsoluteCurrentValue[nb, WindowTitle]
     }
    ],
   Except[WordCharacter] -> ""
   ];

NotebookToPackage[nb_NotebookObject] :=
  With[{cells =
     Replace[NotebookRead[nb], {
       c_Cell :> {c},
       {} :> First@NotebookGet[nb]
       }]},
   With[{data = Reap[cellsBuildPackageCore@cells]},
    With[{usagecells = defsUsagesCell[Flatten@Last@data]},
     Notebook[
      Flatten@{
        Cell[notebookExtractPackageName[nb], "Section"],
        Cell[
         BoxData@
          RowBox[{
            RowBox[{"BeginPackage", "[",
              "\"" <> notebookExtractPackageName[nb] <> "`\"",
              "]"}],
            ";"}],
         "Code"
         ],
        If[Length@usagecells[[1]] > 0,
         usagecells[[1]],
         {}
         ],
        Cell[
         BoxData@RowBox[{RowBox[{"Begin", "[", "\"`Private`\"", "]"}],
             ";"}],
         "Code"
         ],
        If[Length@usagecells[[2]] > 0,
         Cell[
          CellGroupData[
           Flatten@{
             Cell["Private Declarations", "Subsubsection"],
             usagecells[[2]]
             },
           Closed
           ]
          ],
         Nothing
         ],
        Cell[
         CellGroupData[
          Flatten@{
            Cell["Implementation", "Subsection"],
            Cell[BoxData@
              RowBox@{"(*",
                RowBox@{"Package", " ", "Implementation"},
                "*)"},
             "Code"
             ],
            First@data
            }
          ]
         ],
        Cell[
         CellGroupData[{
           Cell["End", "Subsection"],
           Cell[BoxData@RowBox[{RowBox[{"End", "[", "]"}], ";"}],
            "Code"
            ],

           Cell[BoxData@
             RowBox[{RowBox[{"EndPackage", "[", "]"}], ";"}],
            "Code"
            ]
           }]
         ]
        },
      StyleDefinitions -> "Package.nb"
      ]
     ]
    ]
   ];
```

And this'll spit out a package `Notebook` which open with `CreateDocument` we can tweak (mostly just extend the usage messages) and save naturally as a .m file (although for unknown reasons the opened notebook does not take on its new file name and that .m file needs to be opened separately). Alternatively we can open this new notebook with `Visible->False` and use the [`"SaveRename"` token](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/6985/38205) to immediately go to a package file.

It's also worth noting that this whole process could be pretty easily extended to turn a notebook or collection of notebooks directly into a full application with documentation, resources, PacletInfo.m, etc. (since code for autogenerating docs and the PacletInfo.m already exist).

Comment: +1. I've done a few similar things, although not exactly the same. For example, static code analyzer, part of which I posted [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/51333/81) - see if you find it useful, it reports all defines symbols together with the operations used to define them, and accounts for locally scoped variables.  Also, this functionality can play nicely with [MIDE](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/114526/81), which was built based on the concept of notebook-based projects. Unfortunately, I've had zero time to develop tools in the last few years.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin somehow I'd never run into your MIDE project. It's very cool! Particularly as someone who prefers notebook-based development over the Eclipse plugin. When I've got a bit more time I'll see if I can't use some of your static analysis stuff, too. Hopefully by making it easier to move from notebooks to packages more people will write packages, which I can then use :) Long term it would be even cooler if people hosted their packages as paclet servers on the cloud, but maybe that's a pipe-dream.

Comment: Thanks! It's a shame to admit that MIDE development has stalled about 3 years ago (the only feature I added since then was that MIDE now runs on a different kernel than notebooks it manages, which allows the user to safely quit the notebook kernel any number of times without quitting MIDE). And yet I use it on a daily basis and very heavily, in the form it is now. I wish I could find more time and move this project along. Basically I planned to rewrite the core in a modular way, so that people then could start writing plugins.