# How can I automatically generate usage messages?

Tags: function-construction, code-request, code-generation, usage-messages

When programming, I try and name my functions and arguments clearly and document them with `usage::` so I can keep track of everything; e.g.,

```
functionWithALongName::usage = 
  "functionWithALongName[x] transforms x into y with options Opt1-> opt1..."
```

I'd like to automate this process so that the function name, `functionWithALongName`), the variables ,`x`, and the options are included in my documentation instead of having to write them all out.

I'm wondering (a) how do I reference the name of the function called and (b) if anyone has done this and would share their code so I don't have to reinvent the wheel?

Comment: You'll get part fo the way there using `Definition[functionWithALongName]`

Comment: Take a look here: https://github.com/b3m2a1/mathematica-BTools

Comment: @Szabolcs it's actually a different package. See [this](https://github.com/b3m2a1/mathematica-tools/blob/master/NotebookToPackage.m). Or this answer: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/154743/convert-a-notebook-directly-to-a-package-with-boiler-plate/154744#154744

Comment: @Szabolcs that's way more complex than I'm looking for.  I'd like to be able to reference it within, say, a StringFormat function.

Comment: @bills I appreciate the comment, but I'd say that's about 1/4 where I want to go.

Comment: To rephrase my question, is there a way to reference the function being called?  e.g. `functionWithALongName::usage = 
           StringJoin["`` transforms x into wy with options...", internalFunctionThatReturnsName[]]`

Answer (score 3):

Here's a partial implementation, working from the [`DownValues`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DownValues.html) and friends:

We start with a bunch of `DownValues` cleaning:

```
$usageTypeReplacements =
  {
   Integer :> int,
   Real :> float,
   String :> str,
   List :> list,
   Association :> assoc,
   Symbol :> sym
   };
$usageSymNames =
  {
   Alternatives -> alt,
   PatternTest -> test,
   Condition -> cond,
   s_Symbol :>
    RuleCondition[
     Symbol@
      ToLowerCase[StringTake[SymbolName[Unevaluated@s], UpTo[3]]],
      True
     ]
   };
symbolUsageReplacementPattern[names_, conts_] :=
  s_Symbol?(
     GeneralUtilities`HoldFunction[
      ! MatchQ[Context[#], conts] &&
       ! 
        MemberQ[$ContextPath, Context[#]] &&
       ! 
        KeyMemberQ[names, SymbolName@Unevaluated[#]]
      ]
     ) :>
   RuleCondition[
    ToExpression@
     Evaluate[$Context <>

       With[{name = SymbolName@Unevaluated[s]},
        If[StringLength@StringTrim[name, "$"] > 0,
         StringTrim[name, "$"],
         name
         ]
        ]
      ],
    True];
usagePatternReplace[
   vals_,
   reps_: {}
   ] :=
  With[{
    names = AssociationMap[Null &, {}(*Names[]*)],
    conts = 
     Alternatives @@ {"System`", "FrontEnd`", "PacletManager`", 
       "Internal`"}
    },
   Replace[
      Replace[
       #,
        {
        Verbatim[HoldPattern][a___] :> a
        },
       {2, 10}
       ],
      Join[$usageTypeReplacements, $usageSymNames],
       Depth[#]
      ] &@
    ReplaceRepeated[
     FixedPoint[
      Replace[
        #,
        {
         Verbatim[Pattern][_, e_] :>
          e,
         Verbatim[HoldPattern][Verbatim[Pattern][_, e_]] :>

          HoldPattern[e],
         Verbatim[HoldPattern][Verbatim[HoldPattern][e_]] :>

           HoldPattern[e]
         },
        1
        ] &,
      vals
      ],
     Flatten@{
       reps,
       Verbatim[PatternTest][_, ColorQ] :>
        color,
       Verbatim[PatternTest][_, ImageQ] :>
        im,
       Verbatim[Optional][name_, _] :>
        name,
       Verbatim[Pattern][_, _OptionsPattern] :>
        Sequence[],
       Verbatim[Pattern][name_, _] :>
        name,
       Verbatim[PatternTest][p_, _] :>
        p,
       Verbatim[Condition][p_, _] :>
        p,
       Verbatim[Alternatives][a_, ___][___] |
         Verbatim[Alternatives][a_, ___][___][___] |
         Verbatim[Alternatives][a_, ___][___][___][___] |
         Verbatim[Alternatives][a_, ___][___][___][___][___] |
         Verbatim[Alternatives][a_, ___][___][___][___][___][___] :>
        a,
       Verbatim[Alternatives][a_, ___] :>
        RuleCondition[
         Blank[
          Replace[Hold@a,
           {
            Hold[p : Verbatim[HoldPattern][_]] :>
             p,
            Hold[e_[___]] :> e,
            _ :> a
            }
           ]
          ],
         True
         ],
       Verbatim[Verbatim][p_][a___] :>
        p,
       Verbatim[Blank][] :>
        expr,
       Verbatim[Blank][
         t : Alternatives @@ Keys[$usageTypeReplacements]] :>

        RuleCondition[
         Replace[t,
          $usageTypeReplacements
          ],
         True
         ],
       Verbatim[Blank][t_] :>
        t,
       Verbatim[BlankSequence][] :>

        Sequence @@ ToExpression[{"expr1", "expr2"}],
       Verbatim[BlankNullSequence][] :>
        Sequence[],
       symbolUsageReplacementPattern[names, conts],
       h_[a___, Verbatim[Sequence][b___], c___] :> h[a, b, c]
       }
     ]
   ];
```

Then we take a function that uses this to build out a little template for the `DownValues`:

```
generateSymbolUsage[f_, 
   defaultMessages : {(_Rule | _RuleDelayed) ...} : {}] :=
  With[
   {
    uml =
     Replace[defaultMessages,
      {
       (h : Rule | RuleDelayed)[Verbatim[HoldPattern][pat___], m_] :>
        h[HoldPattern[Verbatim[HoldPattern][pat]], m],
       (h : Rule | RuleDelayed)[pat___, m_] :>
        h[Verbatim[HoldPattern][pat], m],
       _ -> Nothing
       },
      {1}
      ]
    },
   Replace[
    DeleteDuplicates@usagePatternReplace[Keys@getCodeValues[f]],
    {
     Verbatim[HoldPattern][s_[a___]] :>
      With[
       {
        uu =
         StringTrim@
          Replace[HoldPattern[s[a]] /. uml,

           Except[_String] :>

            Replace[s::usage, Except[_String] -> ""]
           ],
        sn = ToString[Unevaluated@s],
        meuu = ToString[Unevaluated[s[a]], InputForm]
        },
       (* change this chunk to customize the template *)
       If[! StringContainsQ[uu, meuu],
        meuu <> " " <>


          If[! StringStartsQ[uu, 
             sn | (Except[WordCharacter] .. ~~ "RowBox[{" ~~ sn)],
           uu,
           ""
           ] // StringTrim,
        StringCases[uu, 
          (StartOfLine | StartOfString) ~~ Except["\n"] ... ~~ meuu ~~
            Except["\n"] ... ~~ EndOfLine,
          1
          ][[1]]
        ]
       ],
     _ -> Nothing
     },
    {1}
    ]
   ];
generateSymbolUsage~SetAttributes~HoldFirst;

generateSymbolUsage /@ {generateSymbolUsage, 
  autoCompletionsExtractSeeder}

{{"generateSymbolUsage[f, def]"}, \
{"autoCompletionsExtractSeeder[test, n]", 
  "autoCompletionsExtractSeeder[alt, n]", 
  "autoCompletionsExtractSeeder[pat, n]"}}
```

This doesn't fill out the rest of the template, but we can tweak it like so:

```
generateSymbolUsage2[f_, 
   defaultMessages : {(_Rule | _RuleDelayed) ...} : {}] :=
  With[
   {
    uml =
     Replace[defaultMessages,
      {
       (h : Rule | RuleDelayed)[Verbatim[HoldPattern][pat___], m_] :>
        h[HoldPattern[Verbatim[HoldPattern][pat]], m],
       (h : Rule | RuleDelayed)[pat___, m_] :>
        h[Verbatim[HoldPattern][pat], m],
       _ -> Nothing
       },
      {1}
      ]
    },
   Replace[
    DeleteDuplicates@usagePatternReplace[Keys@getCodeValues[f]],
    {
     Verbatim[HoldPattern][s_[a___]] :>
      With[
       {
        aerger =
         {ReleaseHold@
           Map[
            Function[
             Null,
             ToString[#, InputForm],
             HoldFirst
             ],
            Hold[a]
            ]},
        opa = ToString[#, InputForm] & /@ Options[s],
        meuu = ToString[Unevaluated[s[a]], InputForm]
        },
       TemplateApply[
        meuu <> 
         " takes `nopenopenope`argument`argplur` \
`argggggggggggg``hasopa``oppppppppp`",
        <|

         "nopenopenope" -> If[Length@aerger == 0, "no ", ""],
         "argplur" -> If[Length@aerger == 1, "", "s"],
         "argggggggggggg" ->
          Switch[Length@aerger,
           0 | 1,
           StringJoin@aerger,
           2,
           StringRiffle[aerger, " and "],
           _,
           StringJoin@
            Insert[
             Riffle[aerger, ", "],
             "and " ,
             -2
             ]
           ],
         "hasopa" -> If[Length@opa > 0, " and options ", ""],
         "oppppppppp" ->
          Switch[Length@opa,
           0 | 1,
           StringJoin@opa,
           2,
           StringRiffle[opa, " and "],
           _,
           StringJoin@
            Insert[
             Riffle[opa, ", "],
             "and " ,
             -2
             ]
           ]
         |>
        ]
       ],
     _ -> Nothing
     },
    {1}
    ]
   ];
generateSymbolUsage2~SetAttributes~HoldFirst;
```

and then we're like 80% of the way there:

```
StringRiffle[generateSymbolUsage2@#, "\n"] & /@ {generateSymbolUsage2,
   AutoSyntax}

{"generateSymbolUsage2[f, def] takes arguments f and def", \
"AutoSyntax[f] takes argument f and options \"SyntaxInformation\" -> \
{}, \"Autocompletions\" -> {}, \"UsageMessages\" -> {}, \"SetSyntax\" \
-> False, and \"GatherInfo\" -> True"}
```

This is undoubtedly not my most robust piece of code ever, though.

Comment: I belief this answer is incomplete and requires the function `getCodeValues` that can be found in your other answer https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/164008/45020.

Note that it is used here but never defined. That answer might well contain a more complete answer in general so I think a link to that answer might be useful here.