# How can I automatically generate all the front-end settings for a function?

Tags: front-end, packages, customization, development

I mostly write my packages within the Mathematica FE, but when I develop I never really think all the usage messages, autocompletes, syntax info, and argx patterns that a well developed function would have. And then once it comes time to put them in, I'm generally too lazy to do it.

Can we do this all automatically?

Comment: You have an answer already lined up? Or is this an actual question?

Comment: @Szabolcs I do but I have to pare it down to length... I guess the question posted but the answer didn't.

Comment: The answer showed up now.

Comment: @Szabolcs I had to excise a subsection, but yeah, it's down below the body length limit now.

Comment: Post two answers as a workaround.

Comment: @Szabolcs I need a break from typing--feeling a bit light-headed. I'll improve it in a bit (or once the bug-reports start rolling in).

Answer (score 13):

The answer is a qualified yes.

Yes, we can do all of this, but it won't be as finely tuned as if we did it by hand. There are 4 things we need to handle, `"usage"` messages, autocompletions, [`SyntaxInformation`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SyntaxInformation.html), and [`"argx"` error patterns](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/23356/38205).

I've put this all in a package, so if you just want to use it, scroll to the bottom, otherwise we'll through each step individually:

***( N.B. The package version has a number of little bug fixes and will be actively maintained, please use it until I can make sure all the fixes are in place and merge them here. )***

### Common Code

I had one function common to all the parts of this system:

```
getCodeValues[f_Symbol,
   vs :
    {Repeated[
      OwnValues | DownValues | SubValues | UpValues]} : {OwnValues, 
     DownValues, SubValues, UpValues}
   ] :=

  If[Intersection[Attributes@f, { ReadProtected, Locked}] === { 
     Locked, ReadProtected},
   {},
   Join @@ Map[#[f] &, vs]
   ];
getCodeValues~SetAttributes~HoldFirst
```

It'll keep popping up as we go

### Usage Messages

#### Cleaning the patterns

The first step in generating these messages is knowing what we need from them. In general we want a cleaned form of the arguments to the function, any existing `"usage"` messages, and the function name. If we have a function:

```
test[a_, b_, c_]:=...
```

we want some usage that starts:

```
"test[a, b, c] ..."
```

so that it can be used via the FE [MakeTemplate](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/149802/38205) system (see more of Itai's answers to get a sense for how this works)

Of course, for more complicated patterns we need to be smarter about how we clean. I won't cover all of the cases I tried to handle, but in general I tried to reduce everything to a type or to a `Pattern` name so that I could generate nice `Symbol` forms of the variables.

In the interest of space (as I would otherwise hit the body-length limit on this post), you can see where I did this before in my answer to [How can I automatically generate usage messages?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/155184/how-can-i-automatically-generate-usage-messages/163994#163994)

#### Generating the messages

Then we clean and call `ToString` on the `DownValues` to generate usages:

```
generateSymbolUsage[f_, 
   defaultMessages : {(_Rule | _RuleDelayed) ...} : {}] :=
  With[
   {
    uml =
     Replace[defaultMessages,
      {
       (h : Rule | RuleDelayed)[Verbatim[HoldPattern][pat___], m_] :>
        h[HoldPattern[Verbatim[HoldPattern][pat]], m],
       (h : Rule | RuleDelayed)[pat___, m_] :>
        h[Verbatim[HoldPattern][pat], m],
       _ -> Nothing
       },
      {1}
      ]
    },
   Replace[
    DeleteDuplicates@usagePatternReplace[Keys@getCodeValues[f]],
    {
     Verbatim[HoldPattern][s_[a___]] :>
      With[
       {
        uu =
         StringTrim@
          Replace[HoldPattern[s[a]] /. uml,

           Except[_String] :>

            Replace[s::usage, Except[_String] -> ""]
           ],
        sn = ToString[Unevaluated@s],
        meuu = ToString[Unevaluated[s[a]], InputForm]
        },
       StringReplace["FEInfoExtractor`Private`" -> ""]@
        If[! StringContainsQ[uu, meuu],
         meuu <> " " <>
          Which[
           uu == "",

           "has no usage message", ! 
            StringStartsQ[uu, 
             sn | (Except[WordCharacter] .. ~~ "RowBox[{" ~~ 
                Except[WordCharacter] ... ~~ sn)],
           uu,
           True,
           ""
           ],
         StringCases[uu, 
           (StartOfLine | StartOfString) ~~ Except["\n"] ... ~~ meuu ~~
             Except["\n"] ... ~~ EndOfLine,
           1
           ][[1]]
         ]
       ],
     _ -> Nothing
     },
    {1}
    ]
   ];
generateSymbolUsage~SetAttributes~HoldFirst;
```

You can then use this to build a decent `"usage"` message that will fill via template

```
test::usage = "my test function";
test[a_] := a;
generateSymbolUsage@test

{"test[a] my test function"}
```

### Autocompletions

To get a first sense for how this works look at [this post by Szabolcs](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/129910/38205).

I've been making good use of them for my own things, and have a little system to more conveniently define autocompletion types:

#### Autocompletion Aliases

First I just defined a bunch of aliased forms for the possible autocompletions:

```
$autoCompletionFormats =
  Alternatives @@ Join @@ {
     Range[0, 9],
     {
      _String?(FileExtension[#] === "trie" &),
      {
       _String | (Alternatives @@ Range[0, 9]) | {__String},
       (("URI" | "DependsOnArgument") -> _) ...
       },
      {
       _String | (Alternatives @@ Range[0, 9]) | {__String},
       (("URI" | "DependsOnArgument") -> _) ...,
       (_String | (Alternatives @@ Range[0, 9]) | {__String})
       },
      {
       __String
       }
      },
     {
      "codingNoteFontCom",
      "ConvertersPath",
      "ExternalDataCharacterEncoding",
      "MenuListCellTags",
      "MenuListConvertFormatTypes",
      "MenuListDisplayAsFormatTypes",
      "MenuListFonts",
      "MenuListGlobalEvaluators",
      "MenuListHelpWindows",
      "MenuListNotebookEvaluators",
      "MenuListNotebooksMenu",
      "MenuListPackageWindows",
      "MenuListPalettesMenu",
      "MenuListPaletteWindows",
      "MenuListPlayerWindows",
      "MenuListPrintingStyleEnvironments",
      "MenuListQuitEvaluators",
      "MenuListScreenStyleEnvironments",
      "MenuListStartEvaluators",
      "MenuListStyleDefinitions",
      "MenuListStyles",
      "MenuListStylesheetWindows",
      "MenuListTextWindows",
      "MenuListWindows",
      "PrintingStyleEnvironment",
      "ScreenStyleEnvironment",
      "Style"
      }
     };
$autocompletionAliases =
  {
   "None" | None | Normal -> 0,
   "AbsoluteFileName" | AbsoluteFileName -> 2,
   "FileName" | File | FileName -> 3,
   "Color" | RGBColor | Hue | XYZColor -> 4,
   "Package" | Package -> 7,
   "Directory" | Directory -> 8,
   "Interpreter" | Interpreter -> 9,
   "Notebook" | Notebook -> "MenuListNotebooksMenu",
   "StyleSheet" -> "MenuListStylesheetMenu",
   "Palette" -> "MenuListPalettesMenu",
   "Evaluator" | Evaluator -> "MenuListGlobalEvaluators",
   "FontFamily" | FontFamily -> "MenuListFonts",
   "CellTag" | CellTags -> "MenuListCellTags",
   "FormatType" | FormatType -> "MenuListDisplayAsFormatTypes",
   "ConvertFormatType" -> "MenuListConvertFormatTypes",
   "DisplayAsFormatType" -> "MenuListDisplayAsFormatTypes",
   "GlobalEvaluator" -> "MenuListGlobalEvaluators",
   "HelpWindow" -> "MenuListHelpWindows",
   "NotebookEvaluator" -> "MenuListNotebookEvaluators",
   "PrintingStyleEnvironment" | PrintingStyleEnvironment ->

    "PrintingStyleEnvironment",
   "ScreenStyleEnvironment" | ScreenStyleEnvironment ->

    ScreenStyleEnvironment,
   "QuitEvaluator" -> "MenuListQuitEvaluators",
   "StartEvaluator" -> "MenuListStartEvaluators",
   "StyleDefinitions" | StyleDefinitions ->

    "MenuListStyleDefinitions",
   "CharacterEncoding" | CharacterEncoding |
     ExternalDataCharacterEncoding ->

    "ExternalDataCharacterEncoding",
   "Style" | Style -> "Style",
   "Window" -> "MenuListWindows"
   };
$autocompletionTable = {
   f : $autoCompletionFormats :> f,
   Sequence @@ $autocompletionAliases,
   s_String :> {s}
   };
```

Then we compile these aliases down to the appropriate form:

```
autocompletionPreCompile[v : Except[{__Rule}, _List | _?AtomQ]] :=

  Replace[
    Flatten[{v}, 1],
   $autocompletionTable,
   {1}
   ];
autocompletionPreCompile[o : {__Rule}] :=
  Replace[o,
   (s_ -> v_) :>
    (
     Replace[s, _Symbol :> SymbolName[s]] ->

      autocompletionPreCompile[v]
     ),
   1
   ];
autocompletionPreCompile[s : Except[_List], v_] :=

  autocompletionPreCompile[{s -> v}];
autocompletionPreCompile[l_, v_] :=
  autocompletionPreCompile@
   Flatten@{
     Quiet@
      Check[
       Thread[l -> v],
       Map[l -> # &, v]
       ]
     };
```

Finally here's a quick function for actually setting these:

```
addAutocompletions[
   pats : {(_String -> {$autoCompletionFormats ..}) ..}] :=

  If[$Notebooks &&

    Internal`CachedSystemInformation["FrontEnd", "VersionNumber"] > 
     10.0,
   Scan[
    FE`Evaluate[FEPrivate`AddSpecialArgCompletion[#]] &,
    pats
    ];
   pats,
   $Failed
   ];
addAutocompletions[pat : (_String -> {$autoCompletionFormats ..})] :=

    addAutocompletions[{pat}];

addAutocompletions[a__] /; (! TrueQ@$recursionProtect) :=

  Block[{$recursionProtect = True},
   Replace[
    addAutocompletions@autocompletionPreCompile[a],
    _addAutocompletions -> $Failed
    ]
   ];
```

If you want to test it out you can try this:

```
addAutocompletions[
  addAutocompletions,
  {
   None,
   Replace[Keys[$autocompletionAliases],
    Verbatim[Alternatives][s_, ___] :> s,
    1
    ]
   }
  ];
```

#### Extracting the completions

With that in hand we move to what sorts of completions we can extract. We'll scan over the `DownValues` to find one of three things:

- Colors
- Files
- `Alternatives` of `Strings`

The code then constructs the appropriate positional lists for this:

```
Attributes[autoCompletionsExtractSeeder] =
  {
   HoldFirst
   };
autoCompletionsExtractSeeder[
   HoldPattern[Verbatim[PatternTest][_, ColorQ]] |
    (Blank | BlankSequence)[Hue | RGBColor | XYZColor | LABColor],
   n_
   ] := Sow[n -> "Color"];
autoCompletionsExtractSeeder[
   HoldPattern[Verbatim[PatternTest][_, DirectoryQ]],
   n_
   ] := Sow[n -> "Directory"];
autoCompletionsExtractSeeder[
   HoldPattern[Verbatim[PatternTest][_, FileExistsQ]] |
    (Blank | BlankSequence)[File] | _File,
   n_
   ] := Sow[n -> "FileName"];
autoCompletionsExtractSeeder[
   Verbatim[Alternatives][s__String],
   n_
   ] :=
  Sow[n -> {s}];
autoCompletionsExtractSeeder[
   Verbatim[Pattern][_, b_],
   n_
   ] := autoCompletionsExtractSeeder[b, n];
autoCompletionsExtractSeeder[
   Verbatim[Optional][a_, ___],
   n_
   ] := autoCompletionsExtractSeeder[a, n];
(* actual extractor; delegates to the seeder *)
Attributes[autoCompletionsExtract] =
  {
   HoldFirst
   };
autoCompletionsExtract[
   Verbatim[HoldPattern][_[a___]]] :=
  {ReleaseHold@
    MapIndexed[
     Function[Null, autoCompletionsExtractSeeder[#, #2[[1]]], 
      HoldAllComplete],
     Hold[a]
     ]
   };
autoCompletionsExtract[f_Symbol] :=
 Flatten@
  Reap[
    autoCompletionsExtract /@

     Keys@getCodeValues[f, {DownValues}]
    ][[2]]
(* builds list from extracted data *)
generateAutocompletions[
   f : _Symbol : None, 
   otherAutos : {(_Integer -> _) ...} : {}
   ] :=
  With[
   {
    gg =
     Join[
      GroupBy[
       If[Unevaluated[f] =!= None,
        autoCompletionsExtract[f],
        {}
        ],
       First -> Last,
       Replace[{s_, ___} :> s]
       ],
      GroupBy[
       otherAutos,
       First -> Last
       ]
      ]
    },
   With[{km = Max@Append[Keys@gg, 0]},
    Table[
     Lookup[gg, i, None],
     {i, km}
     ]
    ]
   ];
SetAttributes[generateAutocompletions, HoldFirst];
```

We can test this as follows:

```
test // Clear
test[a_, col : _?ColorQ, f_String?FileExistsQ, "a" | "b" | "c"] := 
  Darker@col;
generateAutocompletions@test

{None, "Color", "FileName", {"a", "b", "c"}}
```

### SyntaxInformation

For this we have four distinct things to handle:

- ArgumentsPattern
- LocalVariables
- ColorEqualSigns
- OptionNames

I only adequately handle the first and last, so I'll only really discuss those.

#### ArgumentsPattern

For this, we reduce the `DownValues` to a more canonical form. First a pattern reduction function:

```
reducePatterns[p_] :=
  Replace[
    p,
    {
     Except[
       _Pattern | _Optional | _Blank | _BlankSequence | 
        _BlankNullSequence | _PatternSequence | _OptionsPattern |
        _Repeated | _RepeatedNull | _Default | _PatternTest | \
_Condition
       ] -> _
     },
    {2}
    ] //. {
    _Blank -> "Blank",
    _BlankSequence -> "BlankSequence",
    _BlankNullSequence -> "BlankNullSequence",
    _OptionsPattern :> "OptionsPattern",
    Verbatim[HoldPattern][
       Verbatim[Pattern][a_, b_]
       ] | Verbatim[Pattern][a_, b_] :> b,
    (PatternTest | Condition)[a_, b_] :> a,
    Verbatim[Optional][a_, ___] :> "Optional"[a],
    _Default -> "Default",
    Verbatim[Repeated][_] -> "Repeated"[Infinity],
    Verbatim[RepeatedNull][_] -> "RepeatedNull"[Infinity],
    Verbatim[Repeated][_, s_] :> "Repeated"[s],
    Verbatim[RepeatedNull][_, s_] :> "RepeatedNull"[s]
    };
```

Whose output I then rebuild into more standardized lists:

```
reconstructPatterns[p_] :=
  p //. {
     "Optional"[a_] :> Optional[a],
     "Default" -> _.,
     "OptionsPattern" -> OptionsPattern[],
     "Blank" -> _,
     "BlankSequence" -> __,
     "BlankNullSequence" -> ___,
     "Repeated"[Infinity] -> Repeated[_],
     "RepeatedNull"[Infinity] -> RepeatedNull[_],
     "Repeated"[s_] :> Repeated[_, s],
     "RepeatedNull"[s_] :> RepeatedNull[_, s]
     } // Flatten;
```

This gives us an `"ArgumentsPattern"` for each individual `DownValues`. We then need to merge these into a maximal `"ArgumentsPattern"`, starting by assigning a pattern `Span`:

```
argPatPartLens[patList_] :=
  Thread[
   patList ->
    Replace[
     patList,
     {
      _Blank -> 1 ;; 1,
      _BlankSequence -> 1 ;; Infinity,
      _BlankNullSequence -> 0 ;; Infinity,
      Verbatim[Repeated][_] -> 1 ;; Infinity,
      Verbatim[RepeatedNull][_] -> 0 ;; Infinity,
      Verbatim[Repeated][_, {M_}] :> 1 ;; M,
      Verbatim[RepeatedNull][_, {M_}] :> 0 ;; M,
      (Repeated | RepeatedNull)[_, {M_}] :> ;; M,
      (Repeated | RepeatedNull)[_, {m_, M_}] :> m ;; M,
      _Optional -> 0 ;; 1,
      _Default -> 0 ;; 1,
      _OptionsPattern -> 0 ;; Infinity,
      _ -> 1 ;; 1
      },
     {1}
     ]
   ];
```

And then merge these term-by-term (i.e. `MapThread` over the `DownValues`) either taking the one that spans all of the others or building a new one if there is no pattern that encompasses them all:

```
mergeArgPats[pats_, returnNum : False | True : False] :=
 Module[
  {
   reppedPats = argPatPartLens /@ pats,
   mlen,
   paddies,
   werkit = True,
   patMaxes,
   patMins,
   patChoices,
   patNs,
   patCho
   },
  mlen = Max[Length /@ reppedPats];
  paddies = PadRight[#, mlen, _. -> 0 ;; 1] & /@ reppedPats;
  MapThread[
   Function[
    patMins = MinimalBy[{##}, #[[2, 1]] &];
    patMaxes = MaximalBy[{##}, #[[2, 2]] &];
    patChoices = Intersection[patMins, patMaxes];
    patNs = {patMins[[1, 2, 1]], patMaxes[[1, 2, 2]]};
    patCho =
     If[Length@patChoices > 0,
      SortBy[patChoices,
        Switch[#[[1]],
          _OptionsPattern,
          0,
          _RepeatedNull | _Repeated,
          1,
          _Optional | _Default,
          2,
          _,
          3
          ] &
        ][[1, 1]],
      Replace[ patNs,
       {
        {0, 1} -> _.,
        {1, Infinity} -> __,
        {0, Infinity} -> ___,
        {m_, n_} :> Repeated[_, {m, n}]
        }
       ]
      ];
    If[returnNum, patCho -> patNs, patCho]
    ],
   paddies
   ]
  ]
```

Then I just apply this to the `DownValues`:

```
generateSIArgPat[f_] :=

  With[{dvs = Keys@getCodeValues[f, {DownValues}]},
   mergeArgPats@
    DeleteDuplicates[
     reconstructPatterns /@
      ReplaceAll[
       reducePatterns /@ dvs,
       {
        (f | HoldPattern) -> List
        }
       ]
     ]
   ];
generateSIArgPat~SetAttributes~HoldFirst

test2[a_] := a;
test2[a_, b_, c_] := b;
test2["a" | "b" | "c", asd_] := asd
test2 // generateSIArgPat

{_, _., _.}
```

#### OptionNames

This is pretty trivial. Just take the `Options` and `ToString` their `Keys`:

```
generateSIOpNames[f_] :=
  ToString[#, InputForm] & /@ Keys@Options[f];
generateSIOpNames~SetAttributes~HoldFirst
```

#### Total function

We'll then take two other functions which I generally don't use to build a total generator:

```
generateSILocVars[f_] :=

  With[{att = Attributes[f], 
    dvs = Keys@getCodeValues[f, {DownValues}]},
   Which[
    MemberQ[att, HoldAll],
    {1, Infinity},
    MemberQ[att, HoldRest],
    {2, Infinity},
    MemberQ[att, HoldFirst],
    {1}
    ]
   ];
generateSILocVars~SetAttributes~HoldFirst
generateSIColEq[f_] :=

  With[{dvs = Keys@getCodeValues[f, {DownValues}]},
   Replace[{a_, ___} :> a]@
    MaximalBy[
     MinMax@Flatten@Position[#, _Equal, 1] & /@ dvs,
     Apply[Subtract]@*Reverse
     ]
   ];
generateSIColEq~SetAttributes~HoldFirst
Options[generateSyntaxInformation] =
  {
   "ArgumentsPattern" -> Automatic,
   "LocalVariables" -> None,
   "ColorEqualSigns" -> None,
   "OptionNames" -> Automatic
   };
Attributes[generateSyntaxInformation] =
  {
   HoldFirst
   };
generateSyntaxInformation[
   f_,
   ops : OptionsPattern[]
   ] :=
  {
   "ArgumentsPattern" ->
    Replace[OptionValue["ArgumentsPattern"],
     Automatic :> generateSIArgPat[f]
     ],
   "LocalVariables" ->
    Replace[OptionValue["LocalVariables"],
     Automatic :> generateSILocVars[f]
     ],
   "ColorEqualSigns" ->
    Replace[OptionValue["LocalVariables"],
     Automatic :> generateSIColEq[f]
     ],
   "OptionNames" ->
    Replace[OptionValue["OptionNames"],
     Automatic :> generateSIOpNames[f]
     ]
   };
```

And here's what that output looks like:

```
generateSyntaxInformation@test2

{"ArgumentsPattern" -> {_, _., _.}, "LocalVariables" -> None, 
 "ColorEqualSigns" -> None, "OptionNames" -> {}}

generateSyntaxInformation@generateSyntaxInformation

{"ArgumentsPattern" -> {_, OptionsPattern[]}, 
 "LocalVariables" -> None, "ColorEqualSigns" -> None, 
 "OptionNames" -> {"\"ArgumentsPattern\"", "\"LocalVariables\"", 
   "\"ColorEqualSigns\"", "\"OptionNames\""}}
```

### ArgX Patterns

Here we'll need a get and set mechanism, just like for the autocompletions.

#### Extracting the arg count

This will use the same toolchain as we had for the `"ArgumentsPattern"`. Now we just need to take the min and max argument numbers and also determine if we have a possible `OptionsPattern` (if we do we want to ignore it when counting arguments).

```
generateArgCount[f_] :=
  Module[
   {
    dvs = Keys@getCodeValues[f, {DownValues}],
    patsNums,
    patsMax,
    patsMin,
    patsTypes,
    doNonOp = False
    },
   patsNums =
    mergeArgPats[
     DeleteDuplicates[
      reconstructPatterns /@
       ReplaceAll[
        reducePatterns /@ dvs,
        {
         (f | HoldPattern) -> List
         }
        ]
      ],
     True
     ];
   patsTypes = patsNums[[All, 1]];
   patsMin =
    Block[{noopnoop = False},
     MapThread[
      If[noopnoop,
        0,
        If[MatchQ[#, _OptionsPattern],
         doNonOp = True;
         noopnoop = True;
         0,
         #2
         ]
        ] &,
      {
       patsTypes,
       patsNums[[All, 2, 1]]
       }
      ]
     ];
   patsMax =
    Block[{noopnoop = False},
     MapThread[
      If[noopnoop,
        0,
        If[MatchQ[#, _OptionsPattern],
         doNonOp = True;
         noopnoop = True;
         0,
         #2
         ]
        ] &,
      {
       patsTypes,
       patsNums[[All, 2, 2]]
       }
      ]
     ];
   {"MinArgs" -> Total[patsMin], "MaxArgs" -> Total[patsMax], 
    "OptionsPattern" -> doNonOp}
   ];
generateArgCount~SetAttributes~HoldFirst
```

#### Setting the arg count

Here we'll just emulate the builtins:

```
setArgCount[f_Symbol, minA : _Integer, maxA : _Integer, 
   noo : True | False] :=
  f[argPatLongToNotDupe___] :=
   (
    1 /; (ArgumentCountQ[f,
        Length@If[noo,
          Replace[Hold[argPatLongToNotDupe], 

          Hold[argPatLongToNotDupe2___, (_Rule | _RuleDelayed | \
{(_Rule | _RuleDelayed) ..}) ...] :> Hold[argPatLongToNotDupe2]
          ], Hold[argPatLongToNotDupe]], minA, maxA]; False)
    );
setArgCount~SetAttributes~HoldFirst
```

### Putting it all together

#### Extracting all the data

Finally, we'll want a function that extracts all of these pieces:

```
Options[generateAutoFrontEndInfo] =
  {
   "SyntaxInformation" -> {},
   "Autocompletions" -> {},
   "UsageMessages" -> {},
   "ArgCount" -> Automatic
   };
generateAutoFrontEndInfo[
   f_Symbol,
   ops : OptionsPattern[]
   ] :=
  {
   "UsageMessages" ->
    generateSymbolUsage[f,
     Cases[
      Flatten@List[OptionsPattern["UsageMessages"]],
      _Rule | _RuleDelayed
      ]
     ],
   "SyntaxInformation" ->
    generateSyntaxInformation[f,
     OptionValue["SyntaxInformation"]
     ],
   "Autocompletions" ->
    generateAutocompletions[f,
     OptionValue["Autocompletions"]
     ],
   "ArgCount" ->
    Replace[OptionValue@"ArgCount",
     Except[
       KeyValuePattern[
        {"MinArgs" -> _Integer, "MaxArgs" -> _Integer | Infinity, 
         "OptionsPattern" -> (True | False)}
        ]
       ] :> generateArgCount[f]
     ]
   };
generateAutoFrontEndInfo~SetAttributes~HoldFirst
```

#### Setting / Dumping the data

Once we have this there are two possible things we might want to do.

- Dump to a file
- Set it on the symbol

If we do the first, we'll want a `Hold`-wrapped expression. If we do the latter life is a bit simpler. Here's a function (the only one I expose in my packaged up version of this) to do that:

```
Options[AutoFrontEndInfo] =
  {
   "SyntaxInformation" -> {},
   "Autocompletions" -> {},
   "UsageMessages" -> {},
   "SetInfo" -> False,
   "GatherInfo" -> True
   };
AutoFrontEndInfo[f_Symbol, o : OptionsPattern[]] :=
 Module[
  {
   sinfBase =
    If[OptionValue["GatherInfo"] =!= False,
     generateAutoFrontEndInfo[f, 
      FilterRules[{o}, Options[generateAutoFrontEndInfo]]], 
     Flatten[{o, Options[AutoFrontEndInfo]}]
     ],
   sops = FilterRules[{o}, Options[generateAutoFrontEndInfo]],
   as = {},
   si,
   um,
   ac,
   argX,
   set = TrueQ@OptionValue["SetInfo"]
   },
  si =
   Replace[
    Replace[Lookup[sinfBase, "SyntaxInformation"],
     Except[{(_String -> _) ..}] :>
      Lookup[as, "SyntaxInformation",
       Lookup[Set[as, generateAutoFrontEndInfo[f, sops]], 
        "SyntaxInformation"]
       ]
     ],
    {
     (Except[_String] -> _) -> Nothing,
     (k_ -> None) :> k -> {}
     },
    {1}
    ];
  um =
   Replace[Lookup[sinfBase, "UsageMessages"],
    Except[{__String}] :>
     Lookup[as, "UsageMessages",
      Lookup[Set[as, generateAutoFrontEndInfo[f, sops]], 
       "UsageMessages"]
      ]
    ];
  um = StringRiffle[um, "\n"];
  ac =
   Replace[Lookup[sinfBase, "Autocompletions"],
    Except[_List] :>
     Lookup[as, "Autocompletions",
      Lookup[Set[as, generateAutoFrontEndInfo[f, sops]], 
       "Autocompletions"]
      ]
    ];
  argX =
   Association@
    Replace[Lookup[sinfBase, "ArgCount"],
     Except[{"MinArgs" -> _Integer, 
        "MaxArgs" -> _Integer | Infinity, 
        "OptionsPattern" -> True | False}] :>
      Lookup[as, "ArgCount",
       Lookup[Set[as, generateAutoFrontEndInfo[f, sops]], "ArgCount"]
       ]
     ];
  If[set,
   SyntaxInformation[Unevaluated@f] = si;
   If[StringLength@um > 0, f::usage = um];
   If[Length@ac > 0, addAutocompletions[f, ac]];
   setArgCount[f, argX["MinArgs"], argX["MaxArgs"], 
    argX["OptionsPattern"]],
   (* dump to held expression for writing to file *)
   With[
    {
     si2 = si,
     um2 = um,
     acpat = autocompletionPreCompile[ac],
     minA = argX["MinArgs"],
     maxA = argX["MaxArgs"],
     noo = argX["OptionsPattern"]
     },
    Hold[
     SyntaxInformation[Unevaluated[f]] = si2;
     If[StringLength@um2 > 0, Set[f::usage, um2]];
     If[Length@acpat > 0,
      If[$Notebooks &&

        Internal`CachedSystemInformation["FrontEnd", 
          "VersionNumber"] > 10.0,
       FE`Evaluate[
        FEPrivate`AddSpecialArgCompletion[
         ToString[Unevaluated[f]] -> acpat]
        ]
       ];
      SetDelayed[
       f[argPatLongToNotDupe___],
       (
        1 /; (ArgumentCountQ[f,
            Length@If[noo,
              Replace[Hold[argPatLongToNotDupe], 

              Hold[argPatLongToNotDupe2___, (_Rule | _RuleDelayed | \
{(_Rule | _RuleDelayed) ..}) ...] :> Hold[argPatLongToNotDupe2]
              ], Hold[argPatLongToNotDupe]
             ], minA, maxA]; False)
        )
       ]
      ]
     ]
    ]
   ]
  ]
```

Here's an example of this at work (note that `"SetInfo"` actually sets the values, otherwise it just generates a form you can put in a file or tweak by hand):

```
test3[a_] := a;
test3[a_, b_, c_] := b;
test3["aaaa" | "bbbb" | "cccc", asd_] := asd
AutoFrontEndInfo[test3, "SetInfo" -> True]
```

The usages:

[image: uuuuu]

Autocomplete:

[image: aaaaa]

Argpat coloring:

[image: pp1]

[image: pp2]

And `"argx"` calls:

```
test3[]

test3::argb: test3 called with 0 arguments; between 1 and 3 arguments are expected.

test3[]

test3[1, 2, 3, 4]

test3::argb: test3 called with 4 arguments; between 1 and 3 arguments are expected.

test3[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

---

### Package version

This is in a package on GitHub [here](https://github.com/b3m2a1/mathematica-tools/blob/master/FEInfoExtractor.wl).

You can then use this like so:

```
<< https://raw.githubusercontent.com/b3m2a1/mathematica-tools/master/FEInfoExtractor.wl
AutoFrontEndInfo@AutoFrontEndInfo
```

Comment: Hi, @b3m2a1. Thank you so much for such a through package. But how to clear info binding of the symbol? I found `ClearAll` doesn't work

Comment: @matheorem I'm assuming the `SyntaxInformation` is giving you trouble? Let me think about this. The hard part is what to do with the `"OptionNames"`. For the most part, though, ``SyntaxInformation[f]={"ArgumentsPattern"->{_,OptionsPattern[]}, "LocalVariables"->{}, "ColorEqualSigns"->{}};SyntaxInformation[f]=.`` will do it.

Comment: I found a made a mistake. I mixed my own autosyntax function with your package. I reboot kernel and load your package, and found that `Needs["FEInfoExtractor`"]; ClearAll[f]; 
f[x_] := x; AutoFrontEndInfo[f]; f[1, 2]` didn't give red color warning. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: @matheorem `AutoFrontEndInfo` generally just generates the info. Use `AutoFrontEndInfo[f, "SetInfo" -> True]` to get it to also set. I do this so I can build it into packages without having to load `AutoFrontEndInfo`.

Comment: Ok, got it. Sorry for my direct jumping to the very end, I should read it more carefully : ) However, there are at least two issues. First, the usage for `test3["aaaa" | "bbbb" | "cccc", asd_] := asd` is not generated properly. Second, What if I add new definition of `test3`, I found it doesn't work for newly added definition after rerun `AutoFrontEndInfo`

Comment: @matheorem yeah that first case is a bit ambiguous so I don't handle the usage entirely satisfactorily. The second is on my radar, but bring it up on the GitHub issues page so I remember it exists. It has to do with also handling the `argx` message and I've never gotten around to handling the corner case.

Comment: Ok, I started an github issue https://github.com/b3m2a1/mathematica-tools/issues/1 : )

Comment: And in terms of `SyntaxInformation`, I think I have a version which has a wilder coverage of cases for options, it is here https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/160275/4742

Comment: @matheorem what cases am I missing that I should include? I tried to be as expansive as possible when generating the syntax info, but things could obviously have slipped through the cracks.

Comment: I have a test function `g` in that post, you can have a look : )

Comment: Oh you include list-type arguments. I thought about including those but I figured it wasn't worth it since none of the built-ins really do that. Maybe I'll include them next time I update this.

Comment: There is also problem about the first argument which should be `{_, __}`, but your version only gives `_`.

Comment: if `g` is `g[{x_,y_}]:=...` that will make a different. My version can highlight g[{1,2,3}] error

Comment: Hi,  b3m2a1. I have a doubt. When I evaluate Needs["FEInfoExtractor`"] I only got `AutoFrontEndInfo`, all other definition in the package is not evaluated. How can I use all other definition?

Comment: They’re in the ``”`Package`”`` subcontext

Comment: I still got some problem.  Because Needs["FEInfoExtractor`Package`"] will fail. If I just use Needs["FEInfoExtractor`"], then Package`generateSymbolUsage  doesn't work

Comment: @matheorem I'm honestly a little confused about what your issue is. This works: ``Needs["FEInfoExtractor`"]; FEInfoExtractor`Package`generateSymbolUsage@FEInfoExtractor`Package`generateSymbolUsage``. As does this: ``BeginPackage["FEInfoExtractor`Package`", "FEInfoExtractor`"]; EndPackage[]; generateSymbolUsage@generateSymbolUsage``. I think it might be worth reading some of the questions on the site about getting packages onto the `$ContextPath`.