# Reset SyntaxInformation completely

Tags: syntax-highlighting

As was pointed out [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/164007/how-can-i-automatically-generate-all-the-front-end-settings-for-a-function/164008?noredirect=1#comment436925_164008) clearing the [`SyntaxInformation`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SyntaxInformation.html) isn't trivial to do.

The best I was able to come up with for clearing it was:

```
SyntaxInformation[f] =
  {
   "ArgumentsPattern" -> {___},
   "LocalVariables" -> {"Table", 0},
   "ColorEqualSigns"->{0, 0}
   };
SyntaxInformation[f] =.
```

But a) this shouldn't require two calls and b) this doesn't handle the `"OptionNames"` parameter. I have no idea how to clear that.

How can we fully reset the `SyntaxInformation`?

Comment: I am here. I just about to post the same post : ) +1