# Auto generate usage message in order to automatically have templates available for user defined functions

Tags: code-request, usage-messages, templates

In order to remind myself of the arguments a function takes and their ordering I find it useful to use the shortcut to show the template (Ctrl+Shift+k). However, I don't write usage prompts for my functions (maybe I should but I find naming the functions and arguments clearly is enough) and so I can't do this for these functions. Therefore I would like to auto generate and run usage messages containing only the function name and the name of the parameters.
I.e. for all my user defined functions such as

```
func[descriptiveArgument1_,descriptiveArgument2_]:= ...
```

I want to create and run (preferably without actually creating corresponding individual cells)

```
func::usage = "func[descriptiveArgument1,descriptiveArgument2]";
```

so that I can see the names descriptiveArgument1 and descriptiveArgument2 in a template with Ctrl+Shift+k.

Comment: In general, this will be very difficult to do as soon as you're using any fancier pattern matching constructs. Having said that, you could take a look at [`ResourceFunction["InformationPopup"]`](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/InformationPopup/) to quickly access function definitions. Finally, this is probably a duplicate of https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/155184/how-can-i-automatically-generate-usage-messages?rq=1

Comment: Thanks, I will look at those! I am not sure it is a duplicate since that question seems to focus on automatically writing a nice usage message for the purpose of having a nice usage message. I don't care at all about the usage message. It only needs to contain func[arg1,arg2]...

Comment: About  `ResourceFunction["InformationPopup"]` do you happen to know where the shortcut Alt+F1 is defined? It does not seem to be in `KeyEventTranslations` I guess because it comes from an additional package. I need to change it since Alt+F1 is already a system wide shortcut for me.

Comment: Regarding the potential duplicate: Couldn't you simply remove all the "nice usage message" parts from the other answer to be left with what you need? Regarding `InformationPopup`: See the last example in the documentation for how to install it with a different shortcut. It will be something like ``ResourceFunction["InformationPopup"]["AddMenuItem", System`MenuKey["X", System`Modifiers -> {"Command"}]]``

Comment: Thanks! I see the example in question. When I copy that command and run it, or if I change the letter so that it isn't something that already has a keybinding, either way no menu item is added and I still only have the old Alt+F1 one. Should I be deleting that shortcut first or something?

About the answer to the other question. Yes I tried whether I could get that to work. It seems it was incomplete and needs the function `getCodeValues` from this answer: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/164008/45020.
It produces the right text which is step 1 towards the answer to my question.

Comment: You'll have to restart Mathematica to remove the old menu item, only then will the new one be added. Also note that you can use `"InstallMenuItem"` instead of `"AddMenuItem"` to make the addition permanent (until you `"Remove"` it at least).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I automatically generate usage messages?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/155184/how-can-i-automatically-generate-usage-messages)

Comment: @Rohit, It was suggested above and I already commented on it. I think it contains an important part of the answer. A small part is left in applying it to all user defined functions. Also note that that answer has incomplete code. I already commented both there and here how to complete it. (I will probably adapt that solution to my problem and answer myself tomorrow.)